# If a operator $L$ in a Hilbert space is self-adjoint, then $L$ is coercive?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators, coercive

Let $H=(H,(\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space and $L:D(L) \subset H \longrightarrow H$ a linear operator densely defined. If $L$ is self-adjoint operator, then $L$ is coercive, that is, there exists $C>0$ such that 
$$(L(x),x)\geq C ||x||^2,\: \forall \: x \in D(L)?$$

I don't know if that's true. I couldn't prove it or set a counterexample.

Comment: Did you mean to have a square on $\|x\|$ in your inequality?

Comment: Yes, $||x||^2$. I fixed.

Comment: What about $L x = -x$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Does not occur.

Comment: Well, this satisfies the assumptions that you put in your question. If you have some further properties you should state these. Otherwise we can only try to guess what you really want to ask.

Comment: @PhoemueX by the hour, I don't know properties anymore. The ones I know are already stated, there are no guesswork and my question is very well put.

Comment: If you choose $D(L)=H$ and $L x := -x$ for all $x \in H$, then $L$ satisfies your assumptions (densely defined, linear, self adjoint operator), but not your conclusion. So either what you want to prove is wrong, or one of us is misunderstanding something.

Comment: @PhoemueX But $D(L)$  is not necessarily equal to $H$. That's why I didn't put that hypothesis, because it doesn't necessarily happen. You're the one who's assuming that. I say the same for the other assumption you made.

Comment: @PhoemueX And I don't want to prove anything, I don't even know if this is true, under the hypotheses stated there.

Comment: It is *not necessarily true* that $D(L)=H$, but *it might be*. I have given you an example which satisfies all your assumptions, but not the desired conclusion. Therefore, you know that your desired conclusion is *in general not true* under your assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inequality would imply that
$$
           \langle (L-(C+\epsilon)I)f,f\rangle \ge \epsilon \|f\|^2,\;\; f\in H,\;\; \epsilon > 0.
$$
And that would force $(L-CI+\epsilon I)$ to be invertible for every $\epsilon > 0$, assuming that $L=L^*$. So, if your conjecture were true, then every self-adjoint operator would have a spectrum that is bounded below.

Comment: Suppose for instance $L$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, with  $v_1,v_1 \in D(L)$  eigenvectors associated. Is true that, for all $w \in D(L)$ such that $(w,v_1)=(w,v_2)=0$ there exist $C>0$ so that $$(L(w),w)\geq C ||w||^2?$$ Is a consequence of the Spectral Theorem?

Comment: In the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973893/coercivity-of-self-adjoint-operator).

Answer (score 2):

What about $D(L) = H$ and $L(x) = 0$ for all $x \in H$?

Comment: $D(L)$  is not necessarily equal to $H$ and it can happen $L(x)=0$ for some $x \in H$.